# Standardized residual by GARCH model shows bimodal distribution, is it normal?

Tags: garch

I fit a GARCH(1,1) model on the spread of 2 correlated assets :

[image]

the GARCH model shows this summary:

```
==========================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|    95.0% Conf. Int.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
omega          0.2066  5.839e-02      3.537  4.042e-04 [9.211e-02,  0.321]
alpha[1]       0.6416  5.479e-02     11.712  1.107e-31   [  0.534,  0.749]
beta[1]        0.3584  6.020e-02      5.953  2.640e-09   [  0.240,  0.476]
==========================================================================
```

From this point, nothing weird, but then when I plot the standardized residual by their conditional volatility :

[image: Standardized residual]

In order to retrieve entry/exit signals for my strategy, I'm doing a 2-tails test on the distribution of these standardized residual. However, as you can see, the distribution is very weird :

[image]

Is it normal to have such bimodal distribution for a standardized residual by a GARCH model ? I'm asking because this is definitely not something I was expecting (standard normal distribution, or at least t-student with fatter tails), neither something I found on the Internet as what we can expect for a GARCH std residual.. What did I miss here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not normal. I bet that you have not specified the distribution of the standardized innovations to be a bimodal one when specifying the GARCH model. If so, your model is misspecified. And even if there was a possibility to specify a bimodal distribution for standardized innovations, you would probably rather prefer to account for the bimodality in the conditional mean (and perhaps the conditional variance) equation instead.

To give an unrelated, hypothetical example, consider the wage distribution of a population. If the distribution for males has a different peak than the one for females, you might end up with a bimodal distribution for the total population. Why not use a sex dummy for the conditional mean (and probably for some higher-order moments) to account for that instead of trying to find a suitable bimodal distribution? The sex dummy approach makes matters more transparent.

Comment: @RichThank you for your answer  If I understand correctly, one should capture as much information as possible in the mean process, and then apply a GARCH only on a residual with constant mean over time, but only with changing variance. Indeed, the spread of the 2 correlated assets that I showed has changing mean over time as you can see. If I apply a VECM on my spread as a conditional mean process, and take its residual, it gives a real constant mean over time (0) and then the std residual looks "unimodal".

Comment: But the problem is that we need an estimate of the variance of the overall spread next period to be able to twinkle entry/exit signals. With a variance of the VECM, I'm not able to have any idea about this variance (because I compute the variance of something else basically). How I could get back to the variance of the spread, in your opinion ?

Comment: @JeremLachkar, not sure if I understand your question. Suppose the cond. mean model is $x_t=\mu_t+\varepsilon_t$ where $\mu_t$ is a function of the past or of an exogenous variable that is available at time $t$. Then the cond. variance of $x_t$ is the (cond.) variance of $\varepsilon_t$. The unconditional variance of $x_t$ is something else, but you probably (?) do not need that as it probably does not make sense to ignore conditioning information that is readily available.

Comment: Sorry, actually I wanted to estimate the *conditional* variance of the spread, at all time. This enables to twinkle entry/exit signals (if spread cond. variance is high, then increase the level at which we take a position). But I have no idea of this cond. variance if I have only a VECM residual conditional variance estimate, since they have no link (or a link that I can't see ?) with the cond. variance of the spread itself. 
That's why I wanted to estimate the cond. variance of the spread in the first place, or get back from the VECM cond. var to the spread cond. var with some formula ?

Comment: @JeremLachkar, does my previous comment not address your question? If you have an estimate of the cond. variance of the residual, that also serves as an estimate of the cond. variance of the dependent variable. The regressors in the cond. mean equation are given, so they do not affect the cond. variance of the dependent variable.

Comment: Looks good but something is wrong intuitively. Say I have a spread that goes from 0 to 60 like in the TS that I plotted in the question, I expect VECM residual to be of a much lower scale, because it'd have capture a lot of the "move". If I plot the VECM residual, I get something that is near 2-3 in low variance times, which is very low compared to the spread *level* that I plot. So if I take it directly as a trading entry point, it will take positions very early right ? I wanted to get back to something that is close to the scale of what can see in the first plot, around 10 I'd say visually

Comment: @JeremLachkar, if you want to extract trading signals from the spread, perhaps you could base them on the distribution of the spread. E.g. you could trade one way when you are in the 10% or lower quantile and another way when you are in the 90% or higher quantile or something. You would obtain these quantiles empirically without modelling the spread anyhow.

Comment: Yes this is somehow what we're doing :) However, in period of high activity, these signals must be adjusted to account for the predictable conditional variance (say the spread goes back and forth from 10 to -10 periodically, and then it slowly increase in scale to go from -30 to 30, the trading signals must adapt and increase their "scale" as well so that it doesn't enter too early.

Comment: @JeremLachkar, OK, now I am with you. Let me think about this...

Comment: That's why we fit a GARCH on the spread, in order to have an idea of where we could expect it to be next period. We wanted actually to take the distribution of the std residuals by the GARCH cond. var., decide and fit a distribution (t-student for example), and take a Z-score corresponding to a p-value <10% for entry signals. 
this would enable to have entry signals depending directly on the conditional sigma forecasted at all time, and we'd take Z times this sigma. 
But then I asked that question because plotting distribution of the standardized spread gave this weird bimodal distribution

Comment: @JeremLachkar, your idea in the last comment seems questionable. If the cond. mean of the spread is not zero, this approach would ignore how large the spread is and only look at the shock; that is probably not what you want. You want to buy/sell when the spread is far away from zero, not when the shock is large. (The shock could be bringing the spread closer to zero rather than further away!) But perhaps you could look at the ratio of the spread and the shock's cond. variance (predicted cumulative for $\tau$ number of periods, $\tau$ depending on the trading strategy) and use that as a signal.

Comment: Yes you're right. I had a misunderstanding about what is called the *conditional* variance and indeed, this corresponds only to the shock, knowing information last period which is very small compared to the spread itself actually. 
Looking at the ratio between both could be a good approach I will try this ! :)